# How to pass value in the screen text fields in a flex application using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, apache-flex

I am currently trying to automate a flex application using Selenium Webdriver. The application works on IE 64 bit. I am able to launch the application. But unable to pass value in Login ID and Password field. I have got the object IDs. Could anyone please help me with the syntax to write for this in order to enter the value and login.

Comment: Add your existing code..

Comment: public class App 
{
static WebDriver driver = null; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\manini.manaswini\\workspace\\test\\src\\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("url");
FlashObjectWebDriver flashApp = new FlashObjectWebDriver(driver,"object");
Thread.sleep(6000);

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't handle flex objects, if you want to automate flex application you need to use selenium with other libraries like,

Adobe Genie: https://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/

SFAPI: https://code.google.com/archive/p/sfapi/downloads

These are some of the available libraries to automate flex, there are lot more(Flex Pilot, Flex Monkium etc) both open source and commercial softwares available.